# [Flutter][AdMob] Can't add iOS app to my AdMob account

Tags: ios, flutter, admob

My Flutter app was published on April 2nd, 2021 on App Store, but it's still not listed in the AdMob search results for some unknown reasons. I've tried to search it by app name, dev name, app ID. Nothing works. I can't create an ad unit for the iOS version. Everything works fine for the Android app version.

It's impossible to contact the AdMob support:

[image: AdMob support]

...and my question in the AdMob Community has been disabled:

[image: AdMob Community]

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: I recently published a blog post on this, you can check here: https://justanotherdeveloper.in/blog/link-new-apps-on-admob-instantly/

Comment: Try to make a ad in Google ads (AdWords). Once the app is indexed. You'll find it on admob.